# argument error while using schedule module?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, schedule

So I'm working on automating my online classes so I'm using a python module **schedule**.

I created a function **tt** which takes 3 arguments **year, month, day**(I will drop a picture for reference)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcXiO.png)

Don't worry about the functions inside the tt function they are just xpaths for classes and a,b,c,d,e are just variables defined with time strings

so I want to schedule my class every day at 11:00 how do I call my function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBDFS.png)
if I call like shown in the picture it is showing an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRC2T.png)
pls, help me out!
thank you!

Comment: Rather than providing your code as an image, please provide it as code using Markdown. You can do this by using \``` to open and close your block of code. You can learn more about this topic with the [Markdown Guide](https://www.markdownguide.org/)

Comment: hey sure thank you i'm new to this platform

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start is with the [documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-pass-arguments-to-the-job-function). It's pretty straightforward and well written and directly addresses the problem of passing arguments to a function with `schedule`. This ought to work:

```py
import schedule

def tt(year, month, day):
    #some functionality here

schedule.every().day.at("12:26").do(greet, year=year, month=month, day=day)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```